# Window Manager removeView(View view)

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am getting exception when i am going to `removeView(View view)` in the Window Manager.

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
AntView mView=new AntView(getApplicationContext());
wm.removeView(mView1);
```

When i try the above code it shows me an Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:381)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.example.testactivity.BackService.onStartCommand(BackService.java:63)
0   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2051)
```

Comment: plz post your com.example.testactivity.BackService.onStartCommand code

Comment: i got my mistake actually i am making object of AntView again and again in my onStartCommand() method

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add mView to wm, so:

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
AntView mView=new AntView(getApplicationContext());
wm.addView(mView,mViewParams);

wm.removeView(mView1);
```